# How to know the hidden caller of a function in linux kernel statically

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have observed that many functions in linux do not have their direct callers.May be they might have been called through function pointers or through some other way. 
I am statically analyzing the linux kernel code for memory leaks. In that I have come across many functions which free an allocation object but I cant figure out the caller of that function.

e.g.
***i915_gem_free_object()*** frees(**obj->bit_17**) object of  *drm_i915_gem_object* structure which is allocated in *i915_gem_set_tiling()* function. But browsing through the code I cant figure out who is calling the *i915_gem_free_object()* function.

Is there any way I can check this statically?
P.S. I am using Linux kernel 3.12

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to statically track function calls through function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

i915_gem_free_object() is invoked through `struct drm_driver`, I think you need to figure out how the driver is invoked this function:

```
static struct drm_driver driver = {
  ...
    .gem_free_object = i915_gem_free_object,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I Didnt mention the same in my question(not unnecessary wanted to drag the question), yes you are right but I am not able to figure out where this structure is accessed to call the respective free function

Comment: That should be in `drm_gem.c`. Check all the callers of      gem_object_free(), also look into drm_gem_object_free().

Answer (score 0):

As most of the kernel is framework(subsystem) based, the features of a particular framework(subsystem) is exported using function pointers, and functions pointers are dynamic in nature. Therefore you cannot actually "know" how the functions are being called, but of course you could always go through the subsystem's code and find out where the functions pointers are being called. In you case, it could be something like this `driver->gem_free_object(obj);` which might be called from various places depending on the situation. Refer `drivers/gpu/drm/drm_gem.c`.

You might as well use `dump_stack()` to print the stack trace onto the kernel log and figure out the caller.